# Twitter user objects Python request

Tags: python, twitter, python-requests

I have the basic paid plan of Twitter. I am trying to obtain users information using this code:

```
import requests
import json
import config

bearer_token = config.bearer_token
url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/users"

params = {'ids': '[4919451, 14151086]',
          'user.fields':'name,description,location,public_metrics,username,created_at,'
               }


def bearer_oauth(r):
    """
    Method required by bearer token authentication.
    """

    r.headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {bearer_token}"
    r.headers["User-Agent"] = "v2UserLookupPython"
    return r


def connect_to_endpoint(url,params):
    response = requests.request("GET", url, auth=bearer_oauth, params=params)
    print(response.status_code)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(
            "Request returned an error: {} {}".format(
                response.status_code, response.text
            )
        )
    return response.json()


def main():
    url = create_url()
    json_response = connect_to_endpoint(url,params)
    json_response = flatten(json_response)
    d = json.dumps(json_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    return d
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am getting this error:

> Exception: Request returned an error: 400 {"errors":[{"parameters":{"ids":["4919451, 14151086"]},"message":"The `ids` query parameter value [ 14151086] is not valid"},{"parameters":{"user.fields":["name,description,location,public_metrics,username,created_at,"]},"message":"The `user.fields` query parameter value [] is not one of [connection_status,created_at,description,entities,id,location,most_recent_tweet_id,name,pinned_tweet_id,profile_image_url,protected,public_metrics,receives_your_dm,subscription_type,url,username,verified,verified_type,withheld]"}],"title":"Invalid Request","detail":"One or more parameters to your request was invalid.","type":"https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/invalid-request"}

Can you help me to improve the function connect_to_endpoint so it works?
Appreciate your answers in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message you are getting, you need to correct your request payload. The `ids` you passed should be a string with comma separated IDs, and not a string **looking like a list** (`[id,id]`) - the `[` and `]` chars needs to be removed. It's documented in [Twitter API  docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/lookup/api-reference/get-users):

> ID: A comma separated list of user IDs. Up to 100 are allowed in a single request. Make sure to not include a space between commas and fields.

Also `user_fields` seems to be containing one `,` too much (at the end in value string) which makes API expect another field name, but as there's nothing you get empty filed name error.

Once your payload is corrected, API should be more happy:

```py
params = {
    'ids': '4919451,14151086',
    'user.fields': 'name,description,location,public_metrics,username,created_at'
}
```